# Hello, I am trying to run a simple web view and I am stuck

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging

Hello I am new to android studio, This is supposed to be a basic web view app, My app launches successfully but the app crashes before it opens to the site. Please help me resolve this, I have restarted the app, restarted the emulator and even tried on another AVD, Thank you.
Here is the code,

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.finalwebviewtekapps

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val url = "https://google.com"
    private lateinit var webView: WebView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        webView.loadUrl(url)
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.finalwebviewtekapps">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FinalWebviewTekapps">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Look in the Logcat. You have a NullPointerException as you did not initialise variable webView.

Answer (score 0):

add this line before setting the web view client

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Answer (score 0):

FindviewbyId is missing on create that's why your app is crashed on launched

**Use this code Before WebViewClient**

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
```